# How to push page down and append a div at top?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, append

What is the best way to push page down `30px`, and put a `div` tag height `30px` at top, like a toolbar?

I tried code as below, but it could not push down page that content div with `position:absolute;` and `top:0;`, or `div` with `position:fixed;`, `z-index:9999;` `top:0;`

```
var divToolbar = document.createElement("div");
divToolbar.id = "divToolbar";
divToolbar.style.width = 100 + "%";
divToolbar.style.height = 30 + "px";
document.body.insertBefore(divToolbar,document.body.firstChild);
```

Comment: I would use `margin-top:30px;` on the uppermost element (a container would be perfect). Also note you can put `100%`, you don't have to use `100 + "%"`

Comment: this is nice example of css poition http://www.barelyfitz.com/screencast/html-training/css/positioning

Answer (score 1):

If the content div has `position:absolute;` it's layout will not be affected by other elements.

You would need to add `top: 30px` to the content div.

Answer (score 1):

As the commenter to your post suggested, this seems to be the best option.

```
.header{
    position:fixed;
    height:30px;
}
.content{
    margin-top:35px;/* or adjust it the way you want  */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the css below for your content div:

```
.content {
    position:absolute;
    top:30px;
}
```